# How do I download "incompatible" extensions from Mozilla's addon website?

Tags: download, firefox-extensions, compatibility

I often find that a Firefox extension I want to download from AMO (addons.mozilla.org) has been tagge as "incomaptible" and greyed out; the grey button often can't be right clicked to download anyway. It didn't use to be that way, and I'm not sure how which way to work around it neatly.

Please note this isn't the same as addon compatibility in Firefox, which is controlled by a config setting. This is about the Mozilla addons website greying out extensions it thinks aren't what you need.  I don't know if it uses User Agent but if it does, I don't want to tamper with it, as this is very widely used to ensure correct working on many websites.

Often you can be downloading on one browser or platform, for use on another and it's incredibly annoying if the website "helpfully" blocks it.

What workaround might help?

Comment: If you go to the dedicated page for the add-on, there are links directly to the publisher's web site and you can download it from there.

Comment: Many addons don't have alternative download links, or there are other issues with the web link. I'd like to download from the add-on page but it quite often just says "incompatible" and the link is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this greyed-out button?

[image: Download Now button]

Because if so, you can still click that and you are given a chance to download anyway:

[image: Download anyway dialog]

Alternatively, you can view the source of the page and search for "firefox/downloads" to get a direct link to the .xpi file.

If you have another specific add-on that's causing different behavior, please post a link to it.

Comment: Yes, that button. The problem is a lot of the time, the link is disabled. So it can't be clicked on. Hence the question.  That dialog in the screenshot is what I expect to get, but often, I can't seem to get it. That's what I'm not sure about, why I'm not getting it and how to workaround it.

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe the Javascript that shows the alternate dialog is failing. You can also view the page source and search for "firefox/downloads" to get a direct link to the XPI.

Comment: I can (or could use greaemonkey in firefox) but... euchhh. Also sometimes the browser isn't ideal for source rummaging, one just wants the link to do what you screenshot above. I'm kind of assuming sense and wondering what's going on, that sometimes its incompatible but clickable (which is fine) and sometimes incompatible and not clickable/disabled (which is a royal pain).  There has to be some cause but I can't seem to figure whats up. I'm assuming it's not a website bug of course but ...??